# How to manage a big collection of files with wordpress?

Tags: uploads, attachments

I have a collection of nearly 3000 swf files that will be used in some of WP's post. Two options that I can think of--

1. Upload them to WP Media Library,they'll become attachments, I can
   query attachment to get them.
2. FTP to host, create database table,
   query them directly.

Which way would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to go with option 2 and alter the DB or use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/, I can't imagine uploading 3k large files through a http interface like the WP uploader.

A 3rd and probably better option is to just use a CDN like amazon to host the media files, since WordPress sucks at this type of thing,

Comment: Love this plugin. Though would great to add a whole folder at once.